# Metric Subspaces

Tags: real-analysis

On page 371 of *The Way of Analysis* by Robert Strichartz we have the following theorem:

*Let $M$ be a metric subspace of a metric space $M_1$. Then a subset $A$ of $M$ is open in $M$ if and only if there exists an open subset $A_1$ of $M_1$ such that $A= A_1 \cap M.$*

The problem is, I can't understand why the following is not a counterexample for the "if" direction:

Let $M_1 = \mathbb{R}^2,$ and let $A_1 = \{x: |x| <1 \}.$ ($A_1$ is the unit ball, which is open.)

Then let $M = \{(x,0) : -0.5 \leq x \leq x \},$ and also let $A=M.$ (The closed line segment from -0.5 to 0.5.)

Then because $M \subseteq A_1,$ we have that $M = A_1 \cap M,$ implying that $A = A_1 \cap M.$

So the hypotheses are satisfied, we have a set $A \subseteq M$  such that there exists an open subset ($A_1$) of $M_1$, and $A = A_1 \cap M.$ But $A$ is not open, because $M$ is not open.

Where am I going wrong here?

Edit: Changed my notation for $M.$

Comment: My notation wasn't clear, but $M = \{(x,0) : -0.5 \leq x \leq 0.5 \}.$ This is certainly a subset of $M_1$, right?

Comment: You still need to fix a typo in your definition of $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A metric space is always open in itself.  Your $A$ is open in $M$, hence there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The statement says that **$A$ is open in $M$** if and only if $\cdots.$

Every metric space is open in itself. So $M$ is, in fact, open in $M.$